# Can anyone match this keyword "/test/" from a large string value through RegEx?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string in the form:

```
var string  = /test/subtest/edit?serialno=someserialnumber&pageCacheId=somenumber
```

I need to extract the substring "/test/" using:

```
var substring = string.match(...);
```

I'm using jQuery.

Comment: do you only wnat to know if the string contains \test\   what language are you using

Comment: *"I'm using jquery language"* jQuery is not a language. jQuery is a library of utility functions/objects, written in a language called JavaScript. jQuery has nothing to do with regular expressions.

Comment: So, you've identified the problem. What has your research turned up? What do your attempts to solve the problem look like?

Comment: this is what you need escape the \ char : \/test\/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex to find the text represented by `/test/` in your example is `\/.*?\/`.

So in JavaScript, using the `.match()` method:

```
var substring = string.match(/\/.*?\//)
```

If you are certain that the value represented by `/test/` in your example will always be at the start of the string then use `^` to indicate to only match at the start of the string. Like this:

```
var substring = string.match(/^\/.*?\//)
```